# ST_Contains. Find all road that are within the scope

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis

I'm try find all road that are within the scope.

That is my request:

```
select osm_id, 
name,
from planet_osm_roads 
where ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=900913;POLYGON((4355764.028 6715445.513, 4364401.418 6715674.192, 4364248.577 6708736.416, 4354808.572 6709155.795, 4355764.028 6715445.513))'), way)
LIMIT 100;
```

or that:

```
select osm_id, 
name,
from planet_osm_roads 
where ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(4355764.028 6715445.513, 4364401.418 6715674.192, 4364248.577 6708736.416, 4354808.572 6709155.795, 4355764.028 6715445.513)', 900913), way)
LIMIT 100;
```

I do everything on the local database, the required data have.

Polygon such:

[image]
The query result is empty.
Tell me what went wrong. Thanks.

Comment: What SRID is your data in? You seem to be using 900913 in your query

Comment: ST_SRID(way) in query returns 900913

Comment: The first example to create a Polygon is correct. LineStrings only contain points that are exactly on the line, as they don't have an area, by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the Spatial Reference.
That's a valid request:

```
select osm_id, name,  
ST_AsText(ST_Transform(way,4326)) from planet_osm_roads 
where ST_Contains(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((39.128494  51.716394, 39.206085 51.71767, 39.204712 51.678942, 39.119911 51.681284, 39.128494 51.716394))',4326),900913), way)  
LIMIT 120;
```

ST_Transform — Returns a new geometry with its coordinates transformed to the SRID referenced by the integer parameter.

Answer (score 1):

[ST_Contains](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Contains.html) probably isn't suited for this job

> ST_Contains — Returns true if and only if no points of B lie in the
>   exterior of A, and at least one point of the interior of B lies in the
>   interior of A.

Since these are roads, at least some parts of it will lie outside your polygon. That means ST_Contains will return false. Perhaps [ST_Intersects](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Intersects.html) might be a better option.

Comment: With "ST_Intersects" is the result, but this result seems to me that I chose the wrong point of the polygon. I've updated the picture and the numbers showed the polygon points. My polygon such 1-2-3-4-1. 
Maybe I'm wrong I form a polygon?

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite understand that comment

Comment: I think that the error in order to specify the points of a polygon. I to point them in the following order: 1-2-3-4-1. It's not wrong?

Comment: It expects a close polygon so the way you are passing the coordinates seems right

Comment: any luck with ST_Intersects